# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined ionic

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making a project in Ionic.

When I tried `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` an error occurred

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

To know the deeper cause　`--verbose`　when using

```
 at /Users/myname/ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/build.js:130:60
```

I was able to identify this as the source of the error but I don't know this error solution.

```js
var promise = require('./list-emulator-build-targets').targetForSimIdentifier(newTarget);
return promise.then(function (theTarget) {
    if (!theTarget) {
        return getDefaultSimulatorTarget().then(function (defaultTarget) {
            emulatorTarget = defaultTarget.name;
            events.emit('log', 'Building for ' + emulatorTarget + ' Simulator');
            return emulatorTarget;
        });
    } else {
        emulatorTarget = theTarget.name;
        events.emit('log', 'Building for ' + emulatorTarget + ' Simulator');
        return emulatorTarget;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share your `cordova-ios` version

Comment: thanks comment

I fixed this issue The comment below is the solution

Answer (score 0):

this error course MacOS Catalina

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/427#issuecomment-503522317

fix code `platform/ios/cordova/liblist-emulator-build-targets`

```
var availableDevices = Object.keys(devices).reduce(function (availAcc, deviceCategory) {
    var availableDevicesInCategory = devices[deviceCategory];
    availableDevicesInCategory.forEach(function (device) {
        if (device && device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch') && device.isAvailable == true) {
           availAcc.push(device);
        }
     });
     return availAcc;
}, []);
```